How to use gdal_translate in Python
I am trying to convert a netCDF file to a Cloud Optimized GeoTiff (COG) format. I have been able to do so successfully in the OSGeo4W Shell using the following command:
gdal_translate -of GTiff NETCDF:my-precip-data.nc:monthly_prcp_norm my_precip-monthly-normal.tif -of COG -co COMPRESS=LZW

However, I want to able to run gdal_translate inside a python script. I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to write to the output folder:
import os
import sys
from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr
import subprocess

input_folder_path = r"C:\MyTest\data"
output_folder_path = r"C:\MyTest\output"
gdal_tranlate = r"C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\geospatial\Library\bin\gdal_translate.exe"

test_input_nc = os.path.join(input_folder_path, 'my-precip-data.nc')
test_output_tif = os.path.join(output_folder_path, 'my_precip-monthly-normal.tif')

command = [f'{gdal_translate} -of GTiff NETCDF:{test_input_nc}:mlyprcp_norm {test_output_tif} -of COG -co COMPRESS=LZW']

output = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

This runs, but nothing happens. The output COG tif is never written to the output folder. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here? I also know that there is a gdal.translate() method, but I don't see good documentation on how to do the above to translate a .nc file to a COG .tif.

What happens if you remove the [] around command?

It had no effect. Nothing was output. My understanding is that using the [ ]'s is the proper syntax for using subprocess.Popen()

It depends, when using shell=True it's not recommended.

if you use shell=True then command should be a string, not list with strings. You could also print(command) to see if it is correct - and copy it to terminal to see if it works. You could also get stdout and display what it has - maybe program displayed some error message.

print(output.stdout.read().decode())

gdal has a python implementation of translate with gdal.Translate(...) method. Have a look here: https://gdal.org/en/latest/api/python/utilities.html#osgeo.gdal.Translate
Also, note that all the common options can be passed as the third argument with gdal.TranslateOptions(...) method.
